# Go install command show 404 error when trying to install module from github

Tags: go, installation

I developed a go module and pushed it to github, when I am trying to install it with the `go install` command its showing

```bash
go: downloading github.com/hvuhsg/lokidbServer v0.0.0-20220825205442-250079f3d6e9
go: github.com/hvuhsg/lokidbServer/cmd/lokidb.go@latest: github.com/hvuhsg/lokidbServer@v0.0.0-20220825205442-250079f3d6e9: verifying module: github.com/hvuhsg/lokidbServer@v0.0.0-20220825205442-250079f3d6e9: reading https://sum.golang.org/lookup/github.com/hvuhsg/lokidb!server@v0.0.0-20220825205442-250079f3d6e9: 404 Not Found
    server response:
    not found: github.com/hvuhsg/lokidbServer@v0.0.0-20220825205442-250079f3d6e9: invalid version: git ls-remote -q origin in /tmp/gopath/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/023bef7fbf7701c1dd80019746ac35a6d71aa94fa9b3961e0dadef371238a56e: exit status 128:
        fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled
    Confirm the import path was entered correctly.
    If this is a private repository, see https://golang.org/doc/faq#git_https for additional information.
```

P.S: the repo is public

The full command is

```
go install github.com/hvuhsg/lokidbServer/cmd/lokidb.go@latest
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install it like this:
`go install github.com/hvuhsg/lokidbServer/cmd@latest`

If the repo is yours, I would recommend adding a folder `lokidb` to the cmd folder, and put the main package inside of it.

Check this repo as an example:

```
go install github.com/fraugster/parquet-go/cmd/csv2parquet@latest
```

Another option is to add a file to the root of the directory, like its done here (in this case, the package inside `go.mod` is defined as `github.com/vektra/mockery/v2`):

```
go install github.com/vektra/mockery/v2@latest
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, but after some time the problem resolved automatically. I've the impression that the cache was giving problems.

try:

go list -m -versions github.com/username/module